# time-out error UART RPi using python-mercuryapi

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, uart, debian-buster

When initiating a mercury.Reader object, the Raspberry Pi should communicate with the M6e RFID reader through UART. This doesn't work. I get a timeout error, the same as when nothing is connected to the UART.

Error as shown below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/code/python/mercury-rfid $ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mercury
>>> reader = mercury.Reader("tmr:///dev/ttyS0", baudrate=115200)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Timeout
>>>
```

System:

- Raspberry Pi 3B / 3B+ (used both)
- Sparkfun RFID reader, using M6 nano https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14066
- Debian buster based Raspberrian
- Python 3.7.3
- API installed by using: pip install python-mercuryapi -b $HOME/tmp [as described in the docs](https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi)

Checks: - The Pi’s UART works, I have successfully communicated between the RPi and an Arduino using UART*

- I have changed the RPi config settings for enabling UART and disabling the Unix serial console [as described here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#disabling-the-linux-serial-console)
- The Pi user is part of the dialout group
- Reader and api work. Successfully scanned tags using an [FTDI LC231X](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_LC231X.pdf) USB to serial adapter (been using this setup for several weeks now) - As described in [this link](https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi/issues/108#issuecomment-647689777), I have modified the TXB0104 by soldering a wire from the VCCB to OE in order to disable the 5V - 3.3V separation and use 3.3V.
- The new setup works, since I have successfully used it with the FTDI adapter in 3.3V mode (has an 3.3V / 5V jumper). But it did not solve the timeout error.
- To fully rule out the hardware I bought new RPi 3b+ and did the same checks as above (i.e. successfully communicated with the Arduino and same time-out error with the reader)

*UART communication between RPi and Arduino as described [here](https://www.teachmemicro.com/raspberry-pi-serial-uart-tutorial/), with this [LLC](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009)

Using the following code:

```
import time
import serial
              
ser = serial.Serial(            
     port='/dev/serial0',
     baudrate = 9600,
     parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
     timeout=1
)
        
while 1:
     ser.write('Hello\n')
     time.sleep(1)
```

I don't know how the python-mercury api addresses the UART under the hood (I have *no* experience with C) but I guess not by using the default Python serial package (i.e. 'import serial' like in the above snipped). Therefore, I assume that's where I should look. In any case, I need some help.

After my last check with the second RPi I am quite sure the issue is within the software, which is why I post it here.
I have posted about this before on the related [GitHub page](https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi/issues/127#issuecomment-1273336100)

Comment: "*I am quite sure the issue is within the software*" -- That may (also) be true, but you haven't completely eliminated any hardware issues.  You seemed to have tested individual interfaces, but not verified the actual RPi to reader connection. Instead of your unproven code, why can't you first test with known-to-work Debian software such as a terminal emulation program like `minicom`?

Comment: Thanks for your commend. I don't know what you mean with 'unproven code'. I haven’t written any code, I simply tried to initiate the reader object of the [python-mercury api](https://github.com/gotthardp/python-mercuryapi). This works when using: RPi>FTDI LC231X>M6 reader.

Comment: You are right about directly testing the RPi-m6e. Which  means I should communicate with the reader in a way different from the python-mercury api. According to the docs bypassing their (Mercury) api with serial commands is not supported.

Comment: Note: I edited my statement wich now says: "I have no experience with C".
Before my edit, the word 'no' was omitted, which is confusing

Comment: I did try RPi-Arduino communication using minicom upon your (@sawdust) commend, which works.